# RadDock and Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 Massive Slow DOwn issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am using RadDock to open a popup. and when i post back any drop down it hangs for some time and   i am retrieving data on other fields after some time.
This issue is only with this new version of chrome in the previous version it was working fantastic.
And also it is working fine with every other browser.

Can anybody give an idea what has been happing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/google-chrome-26-performance-issue.aspx and hopefully they will fix it with their next version.